# my raspberry pi is sending SSH login requests to my internet providers infrastructure?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, malware

Last December I installed a brand new raspi 4B in my office to use as a postgres server.
I installed raspian from the official site, then installed docker and postreSQL
I created a new admin user, secured SSH with a key - and thats pretty much it. All the above steps took multiple tries as I am new to this. But its all working fine now.

Ever since We had trouble with our internet provider. They shut down our internet, saying a device from our office is trying to hack them. At first we though it must be a mistake. We scanned all our computers for malware (including the pi with clamav) and found nothing. But we had 4 internet lockouts ever since and our provider has kind of had it with us, demanding we get an IT specialist in house to find the offending device.
Finally today, they shared a log with me. To my horror I see that the user "pi" is trying to login to some provider side IP addresses via SSH.

So I took the Pi of the network and I am now wondering what to do. They provisionally got the internet back up. But as soon as I plug the pi back in, it will do whatever it is it is doing again - right?

What to do? How is this possible?
I though I had deleted the pi user, but am not 100% sure now. Maybe I did it in my first attempt, but didnt do it in my last install of raspbian? Why did clamav not report anything? [even though I had a lot of access errors during the scan].
I read a lot about how to secure your pi NOW AFTER this all happened. Probably should have done before.

Can I safe this installation plus database - or do I need to scrap the whole thing and start over?

Comment: What does the log say? What process/application is causing this? Please provide code examples and logs in a `code` section so that they are readable. Without specifics it is impossible to ascertain the source of the problem.

Comment: agreed with @fth, maybe it could be useful to have a look at those logs, to identify which service/program is triggering the connection by ssh..in case you/all need to find out what happened..but into a faster move if I were you(advices): reinstall all the raspbian again, into a offline environment, and when you get done the installation(docker,postgre,etc) close the unnecessary ports, change ssh port 22 by other, then create a triggering event to send a sms,mail,etc by anytime a login is done by sshd, have a look on the path: /etc/profile.d/ and over there leave your script.

Comment: totally forgot this question was out there. To close this up: I completely erased my raspiOS installation and started everything from scratch. Followed raspiOS security tutorials closely this time. And for good measure: blocked outgoing port 22 from the raspberry pi on the router.
I dont know who or what it was that caused this. The only thing I did find out was there was a cronjob on the pi user, reinstalling some service daily. I dont remember which one, but I think it was something related to samba.

Secure your raspi immediately after a fresh install!!